# Firebase does not create a Facebook account User UID using the Facebook App User ID

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, fbsdk

I am developing an iOS app in swift that requires a user to create an account by connecting their Facebook account. A month ago, when I was testing by signing up with my own Facebook account, the User UID created by Firebase was in the format "facebook:(facebook app id)". This was what I wanted.

However, lately whenever a user creates a new acconut by connecting their Facebook account with my app, Firebase creates a User UID using a random string. For example: "E9FaL87wRmOKfhen2S6yszhCwtx1". Could this be because of the new Firebase update? Should I go through the migration process?

Here is my code for account creation:

```
@IBAction func facebookAuthAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(nil, fromViewController: nil, handler: {(facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

            FIREBASE_REF.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")

                        FIREBASE_REF.childByAppendingPath("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
                            if snapshot.hasChild(authData.uid) == false {
                                self.createNewFBUser(authData.uid)
                            }
                        })

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
                    }
            })
        }
    })
}

func createNewFBUser(uid: String) {
    var emailAddress:String = ""
    var firstName:String = ""
    var lastName:String = ""
    var pictureURL:String = ""

    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler {(connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let email = result["email"] as? String {
            emailAddress = email
        }
        if let first_name = result["first_name"] as? String {
            firstName = first_name
        }
        if let last_name = result["last_name"] as? String {
            lastName = last_name
        }
        if let picture = result["picture"] as? NSDictionary, data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, url = data["url"] as? String {
            pictureURL = url
        }

        let newUser = [
            "provider": "facebook",
            "firstName": firstName,
            "lastName": lastName,
            "email": emailAddress,
            "picture": pictureURL
        ]
        FIREBASE_REF.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(uid).setValue(newUser)
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should move to the new version of the Firebase, I think Google will shutdown the "old" Firebase soon

Comment: *Firebaser here* The Firebase.com site will remain operational for the foreseeable future. The Firebase 2.x SDKs will remain supported too. That said: we hope our developers will choose to upgrade to our new Firebase console and APIs.

Comment: @Dylan: did you upgrade this project to the new [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I have upgraded to the new Firebase console. But I haven't done any of the other migration process steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade your project to the [new Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), your users are migrated to the new authentication back-end.

Newly created users after the upgrade will get a uid in the new format. See this [post on the firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/uid%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/P07s2r9Ii7Y/zFP63sAsFgAJ) for more information about the change and when it will also be applied to existing (non-upgraded) Firebase apps.

Note that Firebase has recommended against depending on the format of the `uid` for years. It is best to treat it as an opaque string that identifies the user.